# Docker и docker-compose: жизненный цикл контейнеров

Tags: docker, архитектура, docker-compose, микросервисы, микроархитектура

У меня вопрос по архитектуре системы, где несколько контейнеров взаимодействуют между собой.

Пускай у меня в `docker-compose.yml` описана система контейнеров.

Но "время существования" у них разное:

среди контейнеров есть "долгоживущие" - например, база данных, контейнер с которой запущен постоянно. И котрую используют *несколько* других контейнеров.

Или nginx, который служит прокси для соединения "снаружи к внутренним ресурсам".

А есть короткоживущие, построенные для решения одной конкретной задачи по принципу "подняться, сходить на внешний сайт, записать результат в базу и умереть".

Всё это описано в одном докер-композе, и работает в пределах одной `networks`.

И вот проблема: я поднял всю эту конструкцию, у меня отработал короткоживущий контейнер (и умер, завершив свою работу).

До тех пор, пока я не выполню что то вроде `docker-compose stop` - мои "длинноживущие" контейнеры продолжают работать.

*И меня это устраивает!*

Но время от времени мне надо *опять* запустить мой "короткоживущий" контейнер - например, по крону.

Как бы это сделать? То есть, как запустить контейнер так, чтобы он при запуске оказался в той же самой networks и мог взаимодействовать с остальными "долгоживущими" контейнерами?

Потому что каждый раз останавливать-запускать всю эту балалайку - это гораздо дольше, чем "пнуть" один конкретный контейнер.

Мне в голову приходит - сделать еще один `docker-compose.yml`, в котором описан только один этот "короткоживущий" контейнер, и та же самая `networks`, но так не получается, потому что у меня "короткоживущий" контейнер зависит от "долгоживущего", а он уже запущен.

Буду благодарен за советы!

Comment: я вообще не рублю в докере. Но стоит ли ради каждой временной задачи поднмать контейнер? Нельзя поднять один контейнер для всех задач? Типа там какой нить quartz (https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) поставить и пусть он вджобывает по крону или по чему угодно.

Comment: В `docker-compose up` можно указывать имена сервисов https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: @tym32167 - спасибо за совет, интересный проект. я, вообще, вижу некотрые плюсы в том, чтобы ради одной задачи поднимать один контейнер - но что не целую пачку взаимно-зависимых - в этом я уверен... Да и вообще, интересно, как принято решать такую задачу, когда у контейнеров разное время жизни.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov -  то есть, получается, я при первом запуске docker-compose up запускаю его без имён сервисмов, и у меня поднялись все контейнеры. Потом "короткоживущий" отработал и "умер". В следующий раз я выполняю docker-compose up с именем этого "короткоживущего" контейнера - и он один поднимается в рамках всей системы, где остальные контейнеры уже запущены. Так?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - круто, Ваш совет мне полностью помог! Огромное спасибо! Не хотите ли конвертировать комментарий в ответ?

Comment: хз как в докере, но если бы я в AWS такую задачу решал - я бы просто готовый шедулер (типа CloudWatch Events) скрастил с серверлесс темой, например, с лямбдой - оно само будет поднимать инстансы лямбды когда надо, там даже особо настраивать нечего. А если задач много прямо, то я бы между CloudWtatch и лямбдой вкрутил брокер сообщений, типа SQS - например, если у вас миллион мелких задач, а не 2-3 крупные.

Comment: @tym32167 - спасибо, это совет, который мне стОит запомнить на будущее!

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov - я чуть чуть дописал текста и принял ответ. я так посмотрел - Вы иногда очень ценные советы людям даёте по поводу докера! спасибо от всех нас!

Comment: @S.H.,  спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `docker-compose up` можно указывать имена сервисов

```
docker-compose up SERVICE1 [SERVICE2 [SERVICE3 ...]]
```

см. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up

Таким образом, при первом запуске команды `docker-compose up` происходит запуск всех контейнеров - и тех, которые Вы называете "долгоживущими", и тех, которые Вы называете "короткоживущими".

Пускай теперь "коротроживущий" контейнер отработал. Все остальные "долгоживущие" контейнеры запущены, в этом можно убедиться, вызвав `docker ps`

Можно выполнить команду `docker-compose up` c именем этого "короткоживущего" контейнера - и он опять запустится, и при этом будет взаимодействовать с теми, котрые уже запущены.